# How to renice a group of processes?

Tags: process, nice, ionice

`lb build` can build live system image, and it invokes many processes while building the image. If I start it as below:

```
# nice -n 19 ionice -n 7 -c 3 lb build
```

all the children processes get the same nice level:

```
  PID USER       IORR  IOWR    IO IO PRI  NI  VIRT   RES   SHR S CPU% MEM%   TIME+  Command                                                 
26196 morfik        0     0     0 B4  20   0 23888   672   668 S  0.0  0.1  0:00.24 │  ├─ -bash
30926 root          0     0     0 B4  20   0 53668   536   536 S  0.0  0.1  0:00.02 │  │  └─ su -
31008 root          0     0     0 B4  20   0 34656  6260  1144 S  0.0  0.6  0:02.60 │  │     └─ -su
11784 root          0     0     0 ??  39  19  4496   796   524 S  0.0  0.1  0:00.01 │  │        └─ /bin/sh /usr/lib/live/build/build               
11797 root          0     0     0 ??  39  19  4328   612   512 S  0.0  0.1  0:00.00 │  │           └─ /bin/sh ./auto/build
11806 root          0     0     0 ??  39  19  7028   604   504 S  0.0  0.1  0:00.00 │  │              ├─ tee build.log
11798 root          0     0     0 ??  39  19  4496   824   532 S  0.0  0.1  0:00.01 │  │              └─ /bin/sh /usr/lib/live/build/build noauto  
11915 root          0     0     0 ??  39  19  4496   836   544 S  0.0  0.1  0:00.01 │  │                 └─ /bin/sh /usr/lib/live/build/bootstrap  
12753 root          0     0     0 ??  39  19  4496   856   548 S  0.0  0.1  0:00.02 │  │                    └─ /bin/sh /usr/lib/live/build/bootstra
12867 root          0     0     0 ??  39  19 62980  3508  2132 S 11.2  0.3  0:07.00 │  │                       └─ aptitude --assume-yes update
12943 root          0     0     0 ??  39  19 24296  1916  1568 S  0.0  0.2  0:00.14 │  │                          ├─ /usr/lib/apt/methods/xz
12927 root          0     0     0 ??  39  19 53280 30688 30172 R 86.5  3.0  0:28.65 │  │                          ├─ /usr/lib/apt/methods/rred
12891 root          0     0     0 ??  39  19 24304  1784  1440 S  0.0  0.2  0:00.00 │  │                          ├─ /usr/lib/apt/methods/gpgv
12889 root          0     0     0 ??  39  19 24292  1624  1384 S  0.0  0.2  0:00.00 │  │                          ├─ /usr/lib/apt/methods/copy
12887 root          0     0     0 ??  39  19 32860  1956  1560 S  0.0  0.2  0:00.17 │  │                          ├─ /usr/lib/apt/methods/http
12886 root          0     0     0 ??  39  19 24292  1696  1444 S  0.0  0.2  0:00.00 │  │                          └─ /usr/lib/apt/methods/fil
```

But I forgot to add this `nice -n 19 ionice -n 7 -c 3` and ran just `lb build`. So, I tried to `renice` the parent process:

```
# renice -n 19 -p 6187
```

But this doesn't renice the other processes. So, it looks like this:

```
26196 morfik        0     0     0 B4  20   0 23888   668   664 S  0.0  0.1  0:00.24 │  ├─ -bash
30926 root          0     0     0 B4  20   0 53668   528   528 S  0.0  0.1  0:00.02 │  │  └─ su -
31008 root          0     0     0 B4  20   0 34656  5952  1224 S  0.0  0.6  0:02.62 │  │     └─ -su
 6187 root          0     0     0 B7  39  19  4496   800   524 S  0.0  0.1  0:00.00 │  │        └─ /bin/sh /usr/lib/live/build/build
 6349 root          0     0     0 B4  20   0  4328   612   512 S  0.0  0.1  0:00.00 │  │           └─ /bin/sh ./auto/build
 6351 root          0     0     0 B4  20   0  7028   592   488 S  0.0  0.1  0:00.00 │  │              ├─ tee build.log
 6350 root          0     0     0 B4  20   0  4496   828   532 S  0.0  0.1  0:00.01 │  │              └─ /bin/sh /usr/lib/live/build/build noauto  
 6445 root          0     0     0 B4  20   0  4496   840   548 S  0.0  0.1  0:00.00 │  │                 └─ /bin/sh /usr/lib/live/build/bootstrap  
 7580 root          0     0     0 B4  20   0  4496   856   552 S  0.0  0.1  0:00.02 │  │                    └─ /bin/sh /usr/lib/live/build/bootstra
 7692 root          0     0     0 B4  20   0 62924  5236  3848 S 15.5  0.5  0:03.78 │  │                       └─ aptitude --assume-yes update
 7932 root          0     0     0 B4  20   0 54776 16480 15916 R 84.1  1.6  0:16.60 │  │                          ├─ /usr/lib/apt/methods/rred
 7912 root          0     0     0 B4  20   0 24296  2036  1648 S  0.0  0.2  0:01.62 │  │                          ├─ /usr/lib/apt/methods/gzip
 7733 root          0     0     0 B4  20   0 27948  5552  1632 S  0.0  0.5  0:02.85 │  │                          ├─ /usr/lib/apt/methods/bzip2
 7711 root          0     0     0 B4  20   0 24304  1780  1436 S  0.0  0.2  0:00.00 │  │                          ├─ /usr/lib/apt/methods/gpgv
 7709 root          0     0     0 B4  20   0 30800  2200  1812 S  0.0  0.2  0:01.01 │  │                          └─ /usr/lib/apt/methods/http
```

I could renice all the processes manually but they are changing.

**EDIT#1**

The following command:

```
# nice -n 19 ionice -n 7 -c 3 lb build
```

sets also:

> ionice - sets or gets process io scheduling class and priority. ...
>
> -c, --class    scheduling class name or number
>                              0: none, 1: realtime, 2: best-effort, 3: idle
>
> -n, --classdata  scheduling class data
>                              0-7 for realtime and best-effort classes

How to set `-c` and `-n` option of `ionice` to the processes?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since all the child processes are still a part of the session id (`sess` in `ps` output) we could exploit that fact using this command:

```
$ parent=6187
$ ps -eo sess:1=,pid:1= |sed -n "s/^$parent //p"
```

This should return to us all the process IDs of the child processes spawned from `lb load`. We can also get this directly from `pgrep`, using the `-s` switch too.

```
$ pgrep -s $parent
```

We can then `renice` them like so:

```
$ renice $(pgrep -s $parent)
```

#### Example

Here's a contrived example which hopefully illustrates how this all works. We start with a shell, "PID=10515".

**1. Confirm Session ID**

```
$ ps -j
  PID  PGID   SID TTY          TIME CMD
10515 10515 10515 pts/8    00:00:00 bash
30781 30781 10515 pts/8    00:00:00 ps
```

**2. Fake jobs**

We then start up some fake jobs that we forget to `renice`.

```
$ sleep 10000 &
$ sleep 10000 &
```

We confirm they're under our shell's session ID (`SID`).

```
$ ps -j
  PID  PGID   SID TTY          TIME CMD
10515 10515 10515 pts/8    00:00:00 bash
31107 31107 10515 pts/8    00:00:00 sleep
31111 31111 10515 pts/8    00:00:00 sleep
31140 31140 10515 pts/8    00:00:00 ps
```

**3. Get PIDs associated to SID**

We can get a list of all the processes, whose `SID` is 10515.

```
$ pgrep -s 10515
10515
31107
31111
```

**4. Confirm current nice**

What's everyone's nice level currently? Use this command to check:

```
$ ps -eo sess:1=,pid:1=,nice:1= | grep [1]0515
10515 10515 0
10515 31107 0
10515 31111 0
10515 31354 0
10515 31355 0
```

**5. Change nice of all SID descendants**

OK so everyone's `nice` at 0, let's change that.

```
$ renice $(pgrep -s 10515)
31107 (process ID) old priority 0, new priority 19
31111 (process ID) old priority 0, new priority 19
```

**6. Confirm**

Check our work:

```
$ ps -eo sess:1=,pid:1=,nice:1= | grep [1]0515
10515 10515 0
10515 31107 19
10515 31111 19
10515 31426 0
10515 31427 0
```

PIDs 31107 & 31111 are our sleep processes and we just bulk changed their nice to 19 with just the information about what `SID` they're associated to.

**7. Double check**

You can also check `ps` output if you're really paranoid:

```
$ ps -eaf | grep -E "31107|31111"
saml     31107 10515  0 22:30 pts/8    00:00:00 sleep 10000
saml     31111 10515  0 22:30 pts/8    00:00:00 sleep 10000
saml     31531 10515  0 22:35 pts/8    00:00:00 grep --color=auto -E 31107|31111
```

#### References

- [Renicing complex multithreaded applications in Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/195640/renicing-complex-multithreaded-applications-in-linux)
- [Recursive renice?](http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-questions/2003-November/024590.html)

#### `ionice`

If you're attempting to control the processes' I/O priority as well as their nice level you should be able to change the above command example around to something like this:

```
$ renice -n 19 $(pgrep -s $parent)
$ ionice -c 3 -p $(pgrep -s $parent)
```

If you look at the man page for `ionice` you cannot mix `-c 3` with `-n`.

```
   -c, --class class
          Specify the name or number of the scheduling class to use; 0 for
         none, 1 for realtime, 2 for best-effort, 3 for idle.

   -n, --classdata level
          Specify  the  scheduling class data.  This only has an effect if 
          the class accepts an argument.  For realtime and best-effort, 0-7 
          are valid data (priority levels).
```

Comment: `renice` needs also `-n` parameter, so it should be `renice -n 19 $(pgrep -s $parent)`. I also noticed that `ionice` changes. At ` renice -n 19`, `htop` shows `B7`, at `-n 10`, it's `B6`, at `-n -1`, `B3`. This `Bx` correspond to `ionice -n x` , right? Is there a way to set `ionice -c 3` to all the processes, as well as a different `-n` value?

Comment: @MikhailMorfikov - yes the default is 19 if you omit it. Notice in my output above it reniced to 19? What you're asking in the comment above I cannot follow (mostly b/c of the formatting), can you post it as a follow-up Q to your original Q? Just edit your Q and put a **EDIT#1..** section at the bottom.

Comment: @MikhailMorfikov - can you not just run 2 commands using the approach I've outlined above? `renice -n 19 $(pgrep -s 10515); ionice -c 3 -n 7 -p $(pgrep -s 10515)`?

Comment: `ionice -c 2 -n 1 -p $(pgrep -s 8973)` works. If you want to use `-n` with `ionice`, you cannot use `-c 3`. It should be `-c 2` for instance.  Look at the question.

Comment: @MikhailMorfikov - yeah I just realized that in my testing that you cannot mix `-c 3` with `-n`. Well glad we figured it out and your issue appears to be resolved, thanks for the Q!

Answer (score 1):

This is not scriptable, but in htop, you can renice a full tree of processes at once:

- If necessary, press `F5` to enter tree mode.
- Press `Z` (shift+z) to pause updates, then highlight the base process and press `Z` again to unpause.
- Press `c` to tag the base process, and its children as of the last update (which can be quite old if currently paused).
- Hold `F8` to increase the nice level of all selected processes.
- Press `U` (shift+u) to untag all processes.

I'm not sure if htop will tag or renice the wrong processes, if one PID dies, then enough processes spawn that PIDs wrap around by the time you press `c` or `F8`.

Answer (score 0):

```
parent_pid=12345
for pid in $(pstree -ap "$parent_pid" | grep -oP ',\K\d+'); do
  renice -n 19 -p $pid >/dev/null
  ionice -c 3 -p $pid
done
```

Comment: That's been updated. The -n parameter is redundant with ionice -c 3

Comment: Thank you! If it's redundant, you could say so in the answer; I was simply trying to make sure the answer covered the question.